# Send email using Exchange or Domino with ability to add to the user's sent items

Tags: email, exchange-server, lotus-domino

I am looking for a Toolkit/SDK to send emails using Exchange/Domino server. I cannot use SMTP interface since we would like to add this to the user's sent items. Are there any open source/licensed SDK/toolkits that would work with both Exchange/Domino to send emails?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! From the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
You should definitely [take a tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get started :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple toolkits/APIs for Exchange, and there are multiple toolkits/APIs for Notes/Domino. They are very different. There is no toolkit that works with both that can send email messages such that they would be saved in the user's Sent folder.